# Exporting Public Folder ClientAccessPermissions to csv

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

So, I thought that it should be easy enough to
A) Export a list of all our Public Folders
B) Export a list of all our Public Folders with users who have access + access rights. And format it properly -_-

As it turned out, I was wrong, and I'm hoping someone can help me.

A) Get-PublicFolder -identity '\Legal Department' -Recurse -ResultSize Unlimited
Lists all the public folders one by one as expected. Good Stuff.

```
Get-PublicFolder -identity '\Legal Dept' -Recurse -ResultSize Unlimited | ft -property Identity | Out-String | Out-File X:\Legal.PF.txt
```

This one... not so much. After around 10k-18k Public Folders it just stops writing and in one case Powershell crashed with  a warning message. 
It was quite hilarious.

Is there a way around this?
(In case you're wondering, I'm using Out-String to avoid truncation.)

B) Here I am really quite stuck.
I have tried:
    Get-PublicFolder -identity '\Legal Dept' -Recurse -ResultSize Unlimited | FT Identity,User,AccessRights | Out-String -Width 512 | Out-File C:\Legal.PF.Perm.txt

If I just use a subset, i.e. '\Legal Dept\A\Arn', then this works fine, but the formatting is terrible with so many spaces between the columns.

So I've tried to export to csv, but with no luck.

```
Get-PublicFolder -identity '\Legal Dept\A\Arn' | Get-PublicFolderClientPermission | FT Identity,User,AccessRights | Export-CSV C:\Legal.PF.Perm.CSV -encoding "Unicode" -notypeinformation
```

Just gives me this:
"ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd","pageHeaderEntry","pageFooterEntry","autosizeInfo","shapeInfo","groupingEntry"
"033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280",,,,"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo",
"9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,

Not really much use :-/
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Format-Table with Export-csv will not work. You have to use Select-object instead.

Try like this :

Get-PublicFolder -identity '\Legal Dept\A\Arn' | Get-PublicFolderClientPermission | Select Identity,User,AccessRights | Export-CSV C:\Legal.PF.Perm.CSV -encoding "Unicode" -notypeinformation

Answer (score 0):

Get-PublicFolder -Recurse | Get-PublicFolderClientPermis| select-object identity,user,{$_.AccessRights} | Export-Csv publicfoderswithpermission.csv

Comment: Could you explain your answer?